# "Разводятся понятия" - корректный ли оборот?

Tags: лексика

Здравствуйте. 
  Подскажите, пожалуйста, корректно ли в данном предложении употреблять слово "разводятся"?

> Традиционно в исламе разводятся
> понятия "пророк" (набийй) и
> "посланник" (расул)".

Спасибо.

Comment: @Аня Шум-Дождя, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Так сказать можно в неформальном разговоре, но в данном применении это - просторечие, стоящее в одном ряду с такими словами как, например, "разрулить" (проблему). В солидном тексте лучше написать "проводится различие между понятиями".

Answer (score 0):

Нет, конечно. Различаются.

Answer (score 0):

> ...корректно ли в данном предложении
> употреблять слово "разводятся"?

По-моему, корректно. См. аналогичные случаи: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F%22&tbm=bks